# Change main text font only

Tags: fonts, sectioning, formatting, header-footer

I am writing a book and I use `\usepackage{charter}`, but this changes the font of the main text too. How do I keep the font for Chapter title, Section title, header, footer etc of this package and use other font for the main text (i.e. CM Serif)? This is my code so far

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would avise against it. The two fonts do not blend well.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The [`charter` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/charter) changes two elements:

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch}
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}
```

You can just avoid this setting of `\rmdefault` by selecting `bch` (`b`itstream `ch`arter) as-needed. Tapping into the sectional units with [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) is straight-forward, although other options also exist. Also, [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) is typically the go-to when it comes to header/footer customization, but again, other options also exist.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{sectsty,fancyhdr,lipsum}

\newcommand{\charterfont}{\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont}
\chapterfont{\charterfont}
\sectionfont{\charterfont\bfseries}

\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[C]{\charterfont\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\charterfont\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\charterfont\rightmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule (default)
  \fancyfoot[C]{\charterfont\thepage}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```